Gradient checkpointing after model passing
Let’s say that in default setup I have inputs as two 3d tensors like batch_len x seq_len x ebb_size,I pass it through model like and on the output I have 2 3d tensors again, then I got 4d tensor by einsum them like torch.einsum('ijk, mnk -> ijmn', first_tensor, second_tensor) and then reducing it to 2d with sum of maximums, take scores and calculating loss. The problem is that this 4d tensor takes many memory and I can not take big batch size, that is why I want to checkpoint everything before einsum, then calculate einsum of first k batch of first tensor, like torch.einsum('ijk, mnk → ijmn, first_tensor[:k], second_tensor), where k ~ first_tensor.shape[0] / 10, then calculate sum of maximums of these small tensor, calculate loss, remove this small 4d tensor from GPU memory, make same actions with second batch of first tensor, third batch and so on. The main thing is that I want to remove all the 4d tensors from GPU memory. And on the backward we will make forward from checkpoint (output of model passing, but before einsum calculation) and calculate 4d tensor again, but this 4d tensor is a much smaller tensor because of batching, and on every batch we will calculate this small 4d tensor again for calculating gradients, and then remove it from GPU memory again. In my mind it works well. Of course, it works slower because of checkpointing, but it should use much less memory than default einsum with big tensors.
But it is hard for me to implement it in PyTorch. I guess typical torch.checkpoint is not enough here. Can someone help me to understand, how to implement it in correct way, not to crash gradients
